# WebRTC getUserMedia() stream showing static snapshot instead of video

Tags: javascript, video, stream, webrtc, getusermedia

I am trying to stream the screen in a video tag in chrome extension 'options' page (just for testing purpose).I am getting an option to select the screen which I would like to share. when I select it, I do get a stream object which I am assigning to 'video.src', now my video tag shows a static image of the content.

```
$(document).on('click', '#screen_share', function () { 
    chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(["screen", "window"], 
      function(mediaSourceId) {         
          var captureOptions = { 
                                  audio:false, 
                                  video: { mandatory: { 
                                    chromeMediaSource: "desktop", 
                                    chromeMediaSourceId: mediaSourceId } 
                                  } 
                                };
          navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(captureOptions,
                                        function(stream) {
                                          var video = document.querySelector('video');;
                                          video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                                        },
                                        function() {
                                            console.log("Something wrong happened");
                                        }
                                      );
      });
  });
```

Can anyone tell me Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: is it set to autoplay?

Comment: I missed autoplay, now it's working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am going to take a shot in the dark and say your `video` tag is not set to `autoplay` the media source that gets attached to it.

Make sure it is set to `autoplay` and I bet it will work fine after that.

Comment: It didn't work, I didn't put video tag in html. So I need 4 pizzas to be delivered as part of our bet.

Comment: FOUR WHOLE PIZZAS? I am not made of money here man...give a guy a break :)